# Prevent Side Menu Collapse in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse collapse"> 
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">    
                <li>
                    <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Operation <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">               
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"> </i> Request<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>  
                            <ul class="nav nav-third-level">                                        
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<%: Url.Action("ListItems", "Request") %>"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Browse</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<%: Url.Action("EditItem", "Request") %>"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Add</a>
                                </li> 
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hello,

I have a bootstrap (3) side menu who works great but I can't understand why third level collapse (and with him his parent) on click.
I'd like to prevent his collapse and make it works like the second level.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide fiddle??

Comment: [link](http://www.bootply.com/pUlKqjK8jf#)

When clicked Browse or Add, it collapse in, but I want it to stay opened.
Thanks for your help @GuruprasadRao

Comment: Sorry it collapse, it doesn't collapse in.